# How to wait for internal subscribe event to fire in unit testing in TypeScript/JavaScript code?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, jasmine, rxjs5, typescript2.0

I have 2 classes, MyService and FooComponent as shown below:

```
class MyService {
    getStuff(): Observable<Any> () {
        //Implementation that may take sometime to return
    }
}

class FooComponent {
    private myServiceSubscription: Subscription;
    public FooModel : MyDateType;

    constructor(private myService: MyService){
        this.FooModel = null;
        this.myServiceSubscription = null;
    }

    Init() {
        this.myServiceSubscription = this.myService.getStuff().subscribe(response => {
            //Construct this.FooModel from response;
        }
    }

    Done() {
        if (this.myServiceSubscription !== null) {
            myServiceSubscription.unsubscribe();
        }
    }
}
```

The FooComponent takes an instance of MyService and calls getStuff method in its Init method. Note the subscription call using RxJs module. This means the Init method returns before the subscribe event fires. Based on this code, I have following unit test (using Jasmine framework):

```
describe('Component: Foo', () => {

    it('Load Foo Model', (() => {

        var myService = new MyService();
        var instance = new FooComponent(myService);
        instance.Init();

        if (instance.FooModel == null)
        {
            fail("FooModel is null even after calling Init() method.");
        }
    }));

});
```

This test always fails because the test does not wait until subscribe event is fired in the FooComponent's Init method and hence FooComponent instance FooModel is not populated.

What can I do so that some how the test waits for the subscribe event to fire and FooModel is populated?

Comment: I think you should hava a look at http://sinonjs.org/releases/v2.3.4/stubs/

Comment: Mocking of the MyService is not the problem. The question is how to signal that internal subscribe event has fired to the external world.

Answer (score 0):

You should use a stub as @Jin proposed. Most simple way:

```
fdescribe('Component: Foo', () => {

    it('Load Foo Model', (() => {

        var myService = jasmine.createSpyObj('myService', ['getStuff']);
        myService.getStuff.and.callFake(() => {
            return Observable.of(/* response */);
        });

        var instance = new FooComponent(myService);
        instance.Init();

        if (instance.FooModel == null)
        {
            fail("FooModel is null even after calling Init() method.");
        }
    }));

});
```

if you return value from `getStuff` synchronously then callback in `Init` will be called also syncronously and no need in using timeout or something.